# Check if object is valid

Tags: typescript

I am facing an issue when creating a function which checks if an object is valid.

```
const isPeriodValid = (period: Period | null): boolean => {
   return period && period.start && period.end;
} 

export interface Period {
   start: number,
   end: number
}
```

My IDE says:  TS2322: Type 'number | null' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.   Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
and suggests I return: null | 0 | number

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Change your function's signature to `const isPeriodValid = (period: Period | null): period is Period=> {` - that way TSC can use it as a type-guard. Remember that the compiler's type-analysis does not flow local-state across function boundaries (otherwise we wouldn't need preconditions).

Comment: You should also validate that `period.start < period.end`

Answer (score 1):

Well, based on your `Period` type declaration and your function's logic, you're returning either a number or null from your function, so TypeScript takes issue with the fact that your're declaring that you're returning a boolean.

A quick fix solution is to force the result of your evaluation to a boolean:

```
const isPeriodValid = (period: Period | null): boolean => {
   return !!(period && period.start && period.end);
} 

export interface Period {
   start: number,
   end: number
}
```

A cleaner solution would be to create a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates):

```
const isPeriodValid = (period: Period | null): period is Period => {
   return period != null && 'start' in period && 'end' in period;
   // or strictly based on the type system: return period !== null;
} 

export interface Period {
   start: number,
   end: number
}
```

This has the additional benefit that your `period` variable is asserted to be of the `Period` type should you want to use it further down in your code.

Comment: I've edited my question

Comment: If you use the type predicate approach from my answer, you should not be facing that issue. Also, please refrain from moving the goalposts of your question. Ask a new question if you need to.